# Sequelize beforeConnect retry

Tags: sequelize.js

The documentation talks showcases the usage of the `beforeConnect` hook in order to obtain an auth token. Is it possible to request the authToken only when it has changed / expired - in other words, to allow for a retry of the `beforeConnect` hook?